# Have icons on side with background split in three for the three items in the row/div

Tags: html, css, styles

below you will find what the output currently looks like.

[image: Output Demonstration]

I am trying to make the green and yellow extend to the side and meet in the middle (not covering/over the red of the nameplate button. I might not have explained that well, so if you need more information let me know.

The code I have can be viewed and tested in the snippet below. I gave a simple example data line I added to the top of the javascript section.

```js
var interests = document.getElementById("interests")
var data = '[{"firstName" : "Jeff", "lastName" : "Relikeson", "interests" : "3", "pickupLine" : "1"}, {"firstName" : "Harry", "lastName" : "Jackson", "interests" : "2", "pickupLine" : "1"}, {"firstName" : "Bob", "lastName" : "Greene", "interests" : "coding", "pickupLine" : "1"}, {"firstName" : "Jay", "lastName" : "Ding", "interests" : "coding", "pickupLine" : "1"}, {"firstName" : "Jay", "lastName" : "Ding", "interests" : "coding", "pickupLine" : "1"}, {"firstName" : "Brendon", "lastName" : "Hairson", "interests" : "1", "pickupLine" : "1"}]';

load()
        function load() {
            setTimeout( load, 30);
                var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
            var interestsVar = document.getElementById("interests").innerHTML
            var result = dataParsed.filter(x => x.interests === interestsVar);
            var matchesID = document.getElementById("matches")
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var buttonCreate = document.createElement("button");
            buttonCreate.innerHTML = result[i].firstName + " " + result[i].lastName + ";" + "<p class='greenColor'>" + result[i].interests + "</p>" + "Pickup Line:" + " " + result[i].pickupLine;

            if (document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML.includes(buttonCreate.innerHTML)) {

            } else {
                var br = document.createElement("br")
                var br2 = document.createElement("br")
                var br3 = document.createElement("br")
                var div = document.createElement("div")
                var yesIcon = document.createElement("i")
                var noIcon = document.createElement("i")
                yesIcon.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check-square-o fa-5x' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
                noIcon.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-ban fa-5x' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
                var uniqueID = Date.now();
                div.id = uniqueID;
                div.className = "wrapper"
                const matchedIDs = [1];
                matchedIDs.push (uniqueID);
                console.log(matchedIDs)
                
               
                matchesID.appendChild(br)
                matchesID.appendChild(br2)
                matchesID.appendChild(div)
                var divID = document.getElementById(uniqueID)
                divID.appendChild(yesIcon)
                divID.appendChild(buttonCreate)
                divID.appendChild(noIcon)
                yesIcon.className = "yesIcon"
                buttonCreate.className = "matchesDIVs"
                noIcon.className = "noIcon"
                matchesID.appendChild(br3)
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
}

function buttonCreate() {
        var array = JSON.parse(data);
        var resultBoxs = document.getElementById("resultBoxs");
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var buttonCreate = document.createElement("button");
            buttonCreate.type = "button";
            buttonCreate.innerHTML = array[i].firstName + " " + array[i].lastName + "; " + array[i].interests + " " + array[i].pickupLine;

            if (resultBoxs.innerHTML.includes(buttonCreate)) {

            } else {
                var br = document.createElement("br")
                var br2 = document.createElement("br")
                buttonCreate.className = "contendersList"
                resultBoxs.appendChild(buttonCreate)
                resultBoxs.appendChild(br);
                resultBoxs.appendChild(br2);
            }
        }
                }
```

```css
.matchesDIVs {
    box-shadow: 10px 16px 17px -1px #8a2a21;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #c62d1f 5%, #f24437 100%);
    background-color:#c62d1f;
    border-radius:37px;
    border:8px solid #d02718;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1000%;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    padding:10% 10%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.matchesDIVs:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f24437 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
    background-color:#f24437;
}
.matchesDIVs:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 5000px;
}
.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%);
}


.greenColor {
    color: green;
}

.yesIcon {
    background: limegreen;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.noIcon {
    background: gold;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<title>Algorithm</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0\css\font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="load(), buttonCreate()">

    <h1 id="interests" class="interests" contenteditable="true">Your interests</h1>
<div id="resultBoxs"></div>


<div class="container"> 
    <div id="matches" class="center"></div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<button onclick="openAuth()">open Auth</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if you need anything, thanks. -Josh